# Square root of a number with python bisect?

Tags: python

We can get square root of complete square with bisect as follows:

```
import bisect

def squareRootUsingBisect(num):
    return bisect.bisect_left(list(range(0,num)), num, lo=0, hi=num, key=lambda v: v*v)
print(squareRootUsingBisect(169))
```

appropriately prints square root of 169:

```
13
```

The problem is that it also prints a number for non-complete square:

```
print(squareRootUsingBisect(170))
```

prints

```
14
```

which is misleading. Can I determine if `bisect` has indeed found the value or not, and print `-1` or `null` if it has not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bisect_left only gives you the nearest root. If you want to check whether `num` actually is a real square, you have to check afterwards (`bisect` doesn't come with an option to do that)

```
import bisect

def squareRootUsingBisect(num):
    n = bisect.bisect_left(list(range(0,num)), num, lo=0, hi=num, key=lambda v: v*v)
    return n if n*n == num else -1
print(squareRootUsingBisect(170)) # gives -1
print(squareRootUsingBisect(169)) # gives 13
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you just add an `if` check in the function

```
if bisect_calc != num ** 0.5:
    return -1
```